# Warning When Returning Pointer

Tags: c, string, file, pointers, warnings

My file include 1 word in every line(i know the number of the line).I want to read random line, store  it's adress in pointer and return to main function. There is 1 warning (19|warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|) and when i run the program it dont prints anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *word(char *file, char *str);

int main() {
  char *str;
  printf("%s",word("words.txt",str));
}

char *word(char *file, char *str) {
  int end, loop, line;

  FILE *fd = fopen(file, "r");
  if (fd == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    return -1;
  }

  srand(time(NULL));
  line = rand() % 100 + 1;

  for (end = loop = 0; loop < line; ++loop) {
    if (0 == fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd)) {
      end = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!end)
    return (char*)str;
  fclose(fd);

}
```

Comment: Does my definition(char *str= (char*) malloc(x * sizeof(char)) in main or in the function make a difference?Where should i define?What is the difference returning -1 or Null and and finally,please can you clarify about the size of the number to replace x?

Comment: Since the function returns (char *), -1 must be null,i got it, you can ignore this part of my question

Comment: Appreciating for your answer its working,ı just have one extra question that what is the difference between defining str malloc(100) in word or main function

Comment: @theNewPlayer _Never_ do `malloc(x * sizeof(char))` Instead do `malloc(x)` because `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1 [one] on _any_ architecture or implementation, _by definition_. Most arches define `char` to be 8 bits, but some define it to be 16 bits (e.g. TI DSPs). But, on those, `sizeof(char)` is _still_ one. This is because `char` is defined to be the lowest divisible atomic value. That is, the DSP can only address and operate on 16 bit quantities, so it makes no sense to let `char` be 8 bits.